# Failing to verify SSL certificate chain when SSL (.P12) loaded as a embedded resource and not in Certificate Store

Tags: c#, ssl, ftp

I am trying to read the directory contents of a remote site (not controlled by me) using FTP with SSL certificates as authentication.

However when I run the sample code below it fails with the error "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.". It fails on this line `(FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse()`.

I dont expect to see this error. I expect it to validate the SSL chain.

I can get around the error by either:

1. Uncommenting the commented out code below which doesnt fix the error
2. Importing the *.p12 file into the local machine SSL store by double clicking it and going through the wizard (outside of my code and VS). I am trying to avoid having to do this manual step or environment change.

When I read the .p12 file via code  it gives me 2 certificates inside the X509Certificate2Collection or when importing via the SSL wizard gives me two certificates in the local SSL machine store. One is root Certificate Authority (CA) and the client certificate.

Both certificates are valid (in date etc).

I'm unsure how to tell the X509Certificate2Collection that cerificate[1] (client certificate) comes after certificate[0] (CA) in the chain. I think this is my problem so how do I implement this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)        
        {
            X509Certificate2Collection certificateCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Demo.SomeSSLCertificate.p12")) //Embedded resource. In Solution Explorer window in VS, right click file and set build action as "Embedded Resource"
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                certificateCollection.Import(bytes, "SomeSSLPassword", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            }

            string Host = "www.somedomain.com";
            int Port = 21;
            string remoteDirectory = "SomeDirectory";

            string ftpPath = String.Format("ftp://{0}:{1}/{2}", Host, Port, remoteDirectory); 

            FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpPath);

            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = false;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("SomeUsername", "SomePassword");
            ftpRequest.EnableSsl = true;
            ftpRequest.ClientCertificates.AddRange(certificateCollection);

            List<string> entries = new List<string>();

            //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =  

            //delegate(object s, 
            //X509Certificate certificate,
            //X509Chain chain, 
            //SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
            //{      
            //    return true;
            //};

            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        string details = reader.ReadToEnd();

                        using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(details))
                        {
                            string entry = String.Empty;

                            while ((entry = stringReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                entries.Add(remoteDirectory + "/" + entry);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            entries.ForEach(entry => Console.WriteLine(entry));

            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers

Kyle

Comment: You cannot avoid the manual part if you do want to match security criteria.

Comment: Hi Lex. I expect to do this manually somehow but unsure where to start